# JsonAPI nested relationships with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'm trying to handle a JSONAPI response with nested relationships. Ember-Data is currently picking up all of the data in the 'included' property and pushing it all into the correct models, but the relationships between my 'transcription' objects and 'cuepoint' objects aren't working. The relationship between 'video' and 'transcription' objects is working correctly, so it's specifically the nesting portion that I need help with.

Here's an example of the data I'm using:

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"video",
      "id":"55e0687ba1f9e8032c549680",
      "attributes":{
         "title":"Test32"
      },
      "relationships":{
         "transcriptions":{
            "data":[
               {
                  "relationships":{
                     "cuepoints":{
                        "data":[
                           {
                              "id":"55e9b62446942224a0f456cc",
                              "type":"cuepoint"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "id":"55e0687ba1f9e8032c549680-transcription-0",
                  "type":"transcription"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "included":[
        {
           "type":"transcription",
           "id":"55e0687ba1f9e8032c549680-transcription-0",
           "attributes":{
              "language":"English"
           }
        },
      {
         "type":"cuepoint",
         "id":"55e9b62446942224a0f456cc",
         "attributes":{
            "cueIndex":0,
            "startTimeMilliseconds":0,
            "endTimeMilliseconds":4400,
            "text":"- The first one is the L'Oreal Paris Extraordinary Oil."
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Any idea how I can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't tested this particular case, your JSON appears not compliant.

Under the top-level `relationships` key, you place "relationship" objects, and in `included` you place "resource" objects. Resource objects contain relationship definitions.

In short, move the nested relationships outside of the top-level `relationships` and into `included`.

Comment: Does it mention this anywhere in the JSON API spec?

Comment: Quoting: "In addition, a resource object MAY contain any of these top-level members:

attributes: an attributes object representing some of the resource's data.
relationships: a relationships object describing relationships between the resource and other JSON API resources.
links: a links object containing links related to the resource.
meta: a meta object containing non-standard meta-information about a resource that can not be represented as an attribute or relationship." Also see bit on "A "relationship object" MUST contain at least one of the following..."

Comment: You're my hero. Worked like a charm. Your solution makes absolute sense, but my brain was getting tripped up hard by it. Thanks!